# How to get webcam video feed in a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, webcam, getusermedia

I am currently developing an addon where the requirement is to capture the webcam video. I did some testing and noticed that navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() is available within panel and hence have written the following content script for the panel to get webcam video feed from addon.

```
var mediastream;
var mediarecorder;

// Get the instance of mediaDevices object to use.
navigator.mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices || ((navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) ? {
    getUserMedia: function(c) {
    return new Promise(function(y, n) {
     (navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia).call(navigator, c, y, n);
    });
  }
} : null);

function startVideoCapture(width, height, framerate) {
  // Check if the browser supports video recording
  if (!navigator.mediaDevices) {
    return;
  }

  // Lets initialize the video settings for use for our video recording session
  var constraints = { audio: false, video: { width: 640, height: 320, framerate: 25 } };

  // Make request to start video capture    
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
    // Lets initialize the timestamp for this video
    var date = new Date();
    var milliseconds = "000" + date.getMilliseconds();
    var timestamp = date.toLocaleFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.") + milliseconds.substr(-3);

    // Lets make the stream globally available so that we will be able to control it later.
    mediastream = stream;

    // Lets display the available stream in the video element available inside the panel.
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
    };

    // We are not here to just show the video to screen. Lets get a media recorder to store the video into memory
    mediarecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    // Lets decide what to do with the recorded video once we are done with the recording
    mediarecorder.ondataavailable = function(evt) {
        // recorded video will be available as a blob in evt.data object. 
        // The only way to use it properly is through FileReader Object
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Lets decide what we are going to do with the data that we will read from blob
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            // create a video object containing the timestamp and the binary video string
            var videoObject = new Object();
            videoObject.timestamp = timestamp;
            videoObject.video = reader.result;

            // send the video to the main script for safe keeping
            self.port.emit("videoAvailable", videoObject);
        }

        // instruct the FileReader to start reading the blob
        reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.data);
    }

    // Lets start the video capture
    mediarecorder.start();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    self.port.emit("VideoError", err);
  });
}

function stopVideoCapure(){
  if (mediarecorder !== undefined && mediarecorder !== null) {
    mediarecorder.stop();
  }

  if (mediastream !== undefined && mediastream !== null) {
    mediastream.stop();
  }
}

function updateVideoSettings(settings){
    stopVideoCapture();
    startVideoCapture(settings.width, settings.height, settings.framerate);
}


self.port.on("VideoPreferenceUpdated", updateVideoSettings);

// Start video capture
startVideoCapture(self.options.width, self.options.height, self.options.framerate);
```

Now the problem here is the code is perfectly working when from a webpage i.e. if I save the open the panel.html file directly in the browser with proper adjustment of self.options and self.port lines. But when I am using the code in the contentscript for panel in my addon, I am getting the following error

```
JavaScript error: resource:///modules/webrtcUI.jsm, line 186: TypeError: stringBundle is undefined
```

Now that is an error from the inbuilt jsm module in firefox. Is there a way I can get past that error or any other way to get webcam video feed in my addon?

Thanks

Comment: Awesome work! If its a builtin to jsm error, copy paste the jsm contents to your own jsm and fix the line 186, if you find the problem and youre doing things right then lets file on bugzilla.

Comment: I think I know the issue here. This is happening as firefox is trying to get reference of the tab that the document is loaded into. But this script is not running in any tab, instead it is running in a panel. Hence when it tries to ask for the permission for the webcam, it fails. I guess, I can include the jsm into my file and change the code, but not sure if that jsm will get imported into the panel. May be I can get the modified jsm to work with the main script itself instead of making it to work in panel, but that can take time as well. Will check it out later tomorrow morning.

Comment: Went through some of the code of webrtcUI.jsm file. I guess modifying that file and supplying it in contentScriptFile array should solve the issue. But it has now raised another concern in my mind. If this worked, then any one can create an extension with a hidden panel that can capture live webcam video feed without taking permission from the user and can stream it over the internet. Interesting but really scary!!!

Comment: Awesome research! Can you please share a working copy paste example, or installable xpi? Maybe we should create a bugzilla topic and discuss over there? Do you have a bugzilla account, do you need help making a topic?

Comment: I am out for next 15 hours so will need at least 19 more hours to do this. But the research so far shows that we might be completely able to bypass the authorization that is needed for getting access to camera with some simple steps and should get access to camera easily. Once I have the working code, I will share it on the bugzilla. But not sure if this thing should be considered as a bug or not.

Comment: Thanks Gunjan for your research. I thought more about it and I think it will be ok as this is only possible from privileged code. But lets get the first issue fixed at least so it doesn't require a tab :)

Comment: Turns out I was hit by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1007817. Now I am hit by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1122036

Comment: Nice searching Gunjan and thanks for sharing, lets post there and hopefully it will get a fix rolling soon.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I was very curious to see if it works now. We need to get a bug fix or alternative out for this old issue. May you please share your github repo if you have one